# Pass String of Items(varchar) to be used in stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure which will return from provided list of items the selected items from front end.

Tried building strings from selected dropdown list from the frontend. Like:

```
('item.1', 'item.2', 'item.N').
```

Now I want to use it in SQL query with `IN` operator...

Comment: What rdbms are you working with, what connects to the database?

Comment: How will the database know what items have been selected from the front end?  Can you clarify what you're trying to do?  If you're trying to pass in a list of items and select from that, I'd recommend passing in a table variable but I'm not really sure what you're attempting.

Comment: SQL Server 2014 Express. I am going to pass list of items from ASp.net web page Dropdown List, and trying to use AJAX Call. IN SQL Stored Procedure, it will be treated as Input parameter Nvarchar...